# A variant of the generalised assignment problem

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, submodularity

I am trying to solve this problem:

1. There are $N$ workers and $T$ tasks.
2. Each task can be assigned to at most one worker.
3. Each worker can be assigned any number of tasks.
4. The profit obtained by assigning worker $i$ to task $j$ is $P_{ij}\geq 0$.
5. At most $k$ out of the $N$ workers can be chosen to complete the $T$ tasks, where $1\leq k\leq N$.

The problem is a special case of the one discussed [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53030/generalized-assignment-problem-with-overall-budget). Here the budget is $k$ and cost of every worker is 1.

What I have tried: Let $S\subseteq [N]$ be the set of chosen workers such that $|S|\leq k$. For every task $t\in[T]$, to maximise profit, assign it to the worker in $S$ who can bring in the maximum profit. So, the problem becomes:

$$\max_{S\subseteq[N]:|S|\leq k}\sum_{t=1}^T\max_{j\in S}P_{jt}$$.

The objective function becomes an instance of monotone, submodular set function maximization with cardinality constraints, so greedy algorithm yields a $1-e^{-1}$-approximation. I also have a simple counter example to show that greedy algorithm need not give the optimal solution for some instances.

Is this problem NP-hard? I have an intuition it might be, but I am not able to prove it yet. If it is NP-hard, does it admit a better approximation ratio than $1-e^{-1}$? Any hints or references would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: NP-Hard on which parameter? $k$?

Comment: @user3508551 yes.

Comment: @D.W. Sorry, I was not sure which SE was more suited for the question. I asked the question there and as I could not get an answer, I posted it here. Anyways, this version contains more information than the one in https://cs.stackexchange.com, so I deleted the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's problem generalizes the [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem), a well-studied problem for which the best poly-time approximation ratio possibly is $1-1/e$, unless P=NP.  So achieving a better ratio for OP's problem would imply P=NP.

**Lemma 1.** *If OP's problem admits an approximation ratio better than $1-1/e$, then P=NP.*

*Proof.* Given a collection $S$ of sets and an integer $k$, the maximum-coverage problem is to choose a collection $C$ of $k$ of the given sets so as to maximize the size of the union of the chosen sets.

This reduces to OP's problem by taking each set in $S$ to be a worker and each element $i$ to be a task, and letting the profit of assigning a task $i$ to a worker $S$ to be $1$ if $i\in S$ and zero otherwise.  Then the profit of a given collection of sets equals the size of the union.  This gives an approximation-preserving reduction from maximum coverage to OP's problem.

So any poly-time $c$-approximation algorithm for OP's problem would also be a poly-time $c$-approximation algorithm for maximum coverage.  As observed in the [Wikipedia entry for maximum coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem), Feige [has shown](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F285055.285059) that if there is such an algorithm with $c < 1 - 1/e$, then P=NP. $~~~\Box$